# reduceByKey of List[Int]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have `RDD(String,List[Int])`, i.e. `("David",List(60,70,80)),("John",List(70,80,90))`. How can I use reduceByKey in scala to calculate average of `List[Int]`. In the end, I want to have another RDD which is like `("David",70),("John",80)`

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you have duplicated keys or not? Because if not, then there is no point in using `reduceByKey`? Or did you get the `List[Int]` after a `groupByKey`?

Answer (score -1):

Something based on `reduceByKey` doesn't *directly* look good because of it's type signature:

```scala
def reduceByKey(func: (V, V) => V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

`V` in your case is `List[Int]` so you're getting a `RDD[(String, List[Int])]`.

A workaround is use a `List` of one element, the actual average:

```scala
  val rddAvg: RDD[(String, Int)] =
    rdd1
      .reduceByKey { case (key, numbers) => List(numbers.sum / numbers.length) }
      .mapValues(_.head)
```

You could as well attempt something based on `aggregateByKey`: this function can return a different result type and would do the trick in one step.

**Later edit:** I dropped the example with `groupByKey` as it is performance wise inferior to `reduceByKey` or `aggregateByKey` for a use-case like computing an average

Comment: `groupByKey` may blow up your cluster by the excessive amount of memory, it is not recommended to use.

Comment: I offered solutions based on both `reduceByKey` and `groupByKey`.
`groupByKey` is and will be part of the API, it's performance wise inferior to say `aggregateByKey ` or `reduceByKey` when doing simple stuff like averages by key like in our example.

Answer (score -2):

```scala
val data1 = List(("David", List(60, 70, 80)), ("John", List(70, 80, 90)))
    
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(data1)
    
print(rdd1.mapValues(value => value.sum.toDouble / value.size).collect)
```

Comment: Please don't post just code, explain it ;)